# How to receive Apple ID TFA code if I logout of iPhone?

Tags: iphone, apple-id

I need to logout of my Apple ID on my iPhone.  I have Two-Factor Authentication (TFA) enabled, and [according to Apple Support](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204915#FAQ) TFA can no-longer be disabled.

> **Can I turn off two-factor authentication after I’ve turned it on?**
>
> If you already use two-factor authentication, you can no longer turn
>   it off. Certain features in the latest versions of iOS and macOS
>   require this extra level of security, which is designed to protect
>   your information. If you recently updated your account, however, you
>   can unenroll for a period of two weeks. Just open your enrollment
>   confirmation email and click the link to return to your previous
>   security settings. Keep in mind, this makes your account less secure
>   and means that you can't use features that require a higher level of
>   security.

So if I logout on my iPhone, and want to log back in, how can I receive the TFA code to authorise the login?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have multiple options:

You could in advance set a trusted phone numbers for your Apple ID. Then when you want to log back into the Apple ID, you can click "Didn't get a code" to have the code sent to your trusted phone number via text message or automated voice call.

Another possibility is to sign in to the Apple ID with a browser. There you can select to trust the browser. Then you will be able to sign in to the Apple ID using that browser on that specific computer without having to enter a 2FA code.

You will find Apple's guide for two-factor authentication here:

https://support.apple.com/en-gb/HT204915

Comment: Thank you!  The first suggestion "Didn't get a code" worked perfectly, I was able to log out and log back into my Apple ID on my iphone - I had missed that option when I read through the TFA page.  I didn't really understand your second suggestion about the browser though - I'm not sure how signing into a browser would mean I don't need to enter a 2FA code?  Although I see you say "on that specific computer" so maybe it doesn't apply to phones?

Comment: On the browser you can choose to store a token so that you only need a 2FA code the first time you sign on with that browser.